# How to get the image resolution of media from instagram graph api

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

On the previous api of instagram, getting the recent media returns also the resolutions of each. But in the new instagram graph api, it was removed. is there any work around to get the resolution from instagram graph api?